# Error: incompatible operand types and object 

Tags: java, jsp

In the below Java code which is placed in a JSP file,

```
if (false == session.getAttribute("loggedin")) {  
    response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
}
else if (null == session.getAttribute("loggedin")) {
    response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
}
```

I am getting the following compilation error:

> incompatible operand types and object

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: I just put this in a sample JSP and I did not get any errors. I'm running with Jetty 8.1.5 and Java 1.7.0_07

Comment: @andyb: OP is apparently not using Java 1.5 or newer to compile JSPs.

Comment: @BalusC thanks for clarifying. I was about to install an older version to test the code against :-)

Comment: @andyb: explanation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`session.getAttribute()` returns an Object. An Object can't be compared to a boolean. So the expression `false == session.getAttribute("loggedin")` is invalid. If you want to check if `Boolean.FALSE` is stored in the session attribute, the code should be

```
 if (Boolean.FALSE.equals(session.getAttribute("loggedin")))
```

Note that you'd better put all the Java code in regular Java classes and limit yourself to the JSP [EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) in the JSPs. Scriptlets should not be used anymore.